# Unrecognized Character issue in brain JS training and output

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence

I'm using brain JS for predicting some data using 'recurrent LSTM'. I'm using nodeJS as the interface and using express to train it and predict output.

Here is some basic training data :

```
var net = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();    
net.train([
      { input: 'I feel great about the world!', output: 'happy' },
      { input: 'The world is a terrible place!', output: 'sad' },
    ]);
```

Training Part :

```
app.get('/learn', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.query;
    if( params.str !== '' )
    {
        net.train([
            { input: params.str, output: params.output }
        ]);
        res.send('Training Done');
    }
    else{
        res.send('Nothing to train');
    }
});
```

Output :

```
app.get('/predict', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.query;
    if( params.str !== '' )
    {
        var output = net.run(params.str);  // 'happy'
        res.send(output);
    }
    else{
        res.send('Nothing to predict');
    }
});
```

Now the issue appears when I'm using any of the following letters anywhere in the string for training or for prediction.

> j k m n q v x z

Exact error String :

```
Error: unrecognized character "q"
    at DataFormatter.toIndexes (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/brain.js/dist/utilities/data-formatter.js:85:17)
    at DataFormatter.toIndexesInputOutput (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/brain.js/dist/utilities/data-formatter.js:101:23)
    at LSTM.formatDataIn (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/brain.js/dist/recurrent/rnn.js:766:35)
    at LSTM.run (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/brain.js/dist/recurrent/rnn.js:378:24)
    at /var/www/html/brainjs/index.js:56:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/www/html/brainjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can put bit light on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known [issue](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/issues/217).

They have fixed it.

https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/pull/241